# Voltage divider for SSR input

Tags: voltage-divider, solid-state-relay

I have an SSR that takes 3-32V as an input. The trigger current is 7.5mA/12V.

Can I use two 4K resistors as a voltage divider to allow a 14V to 55V power supply to be connected?

The load side of the SSR is a 12V drop down regulator.

Alternatively is there a better option to switch everything on/off?

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SSR40DA.pdf Data Sheet for the SSR.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000262700918.html the drop down regulator.

Answer:
After the answers in the question. I have ended up going with a proper voltage regulator

Comment: any link for the ssr pls?

Answer (score 1):

You could build this with discrete components, but there is a packaged one-part [solution](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Diodes-Incorporated-ZXTR2005K-13_C444408.pdf) for this problem:

[image]

This provides output of 5.0V at adequate output current for inputs from 10V up. It can also withstand spikes of up to 100V, useful safety factor in case there are some transients.

Power dissipation at 55V in should be less than 0.4W.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a voltage divider to allow a 14V to 55V power supply to be connected?

A voltage divider sounds like it could work, yes.

> Can I use two 4K resistors as a voltage divider

You mean 4 kΩ, not 4 K – 4K means "four Kelvin", and that's damn cold, but not a resistance. "k" like "kilo" is written with a small letter up front.

Let's see: 14 V / (2· 4 kΩ) = 14/8 mA, which is a little less than 2 mA.

Your SSR will potentially draw much more current than your voltage divider does in itself, so the upper and lower resistors will experience a very different current, and the divider is a *loaded* divider.

That won't work. You need to use much smaller resistor values, so that the current through the divider is so large that adding the current through the SSR doesn't matter. A factor of 10 to 100 larger current is usual.

> The load side of the SSR is a 12V drop down regulator.

That doesn't sound like an application for an SSR at all – simply control the regulator. Practically all regulators I can think of have something like an "enable" pin, or some other low-effort method to control them. You can either directly control that bin (single transistor), or if you actually need the galvanic isolation, with an optocoupler.

If your regulator doesn't have that, replace the regulator with one that has, instead of adding an unnecessary SSR to your system.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000262700918.html is the drop down regulator I am using.

Comment: I don't know that device, but I guess it comes with a datasheet that tells you how to en- or disable it. So, go read that datasheet!

Answer (score 0):

The SSR has a constant current limiter on the input. That's why it can operate over the range 3 to 32 V DC. Based on the 7.5 mA current draw at 12 V we can assume that it will be fairly close to 7.5 mA for any input voltage in the range 3 to 32 V. (If it wasn't the opto-LED wouldn't have enough current at low voltages.)

We could just add a series resistor to drop enough voltage to keep the voltage at the input below 32 V but you're looking for a 4:1 max:min input range so let's see what happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFu2z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A simple voltage-dropper. (b) A Zener voltage limiter.*

- V<sub>in-max</sub> = 32 V. Let's work with 30 V.
- V<sub>+max</sub> = 55 V.
- V<sub>R1</sub> = 55 - 30 = 25 V.
- I = 7.5 mA.
- R1 = V / I = 25 / 7.5m = 3.3 kΩ.

Now check what current we'll get at 14 V assuming that the SSR will drop 3 V.

- I = V / R = (14 - 3) / 3k3 = 3.3 mA.

This isn't going to work. The current is not enough.

---

Let's design instead for the minimum voltage.

- R<sub>2</sub> = V / I = (14 - 3) / 7.5m = 1.5 kΩ.

Now let's shunt off the excess voltage with a Zener diode.

- With the modification shown in Figure 1b and setting R2 = 1.5 kΩ the Zener diode will be on the point of conduction when the SSR voltage is 30 V. At this point V+ will be 30 + IR<sub>2</sub> = 30 + 7.5m × 1k5 = 41 V.
- If we increase V+ to 55 V the Zener will conduct. V<sub>R2</sub> = 55 - 30 = 25 V. I<sub>R2</sub> = 25 / 1k5 = 16.7 mA of which 7.5 mA will go through the SSR and the remaining 9 mA will go through the Zener.
- The Zener power dissipation will be VI = 30 × 9m = 270 mW. I'd go for a 1 W Zener to stay cool.

---

All of this is based on the assumption that the SSR input draws a fairly constant current over the specified input voltage range. You should verify that using a variable power supply or several fixed voltages while measuring the input current.